# PHP: Create array from MySQL to build HTML calendar

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

currently I am working on a small booking system for what I want to create an overview of already booked time slots.

In my database the booking information is saved like this:

```
_______________________________________________________________
|id|user_id|     starttime     |      endtime      |facilityID|
---------------------------------------------------------------
|1 |    100|2017-08-21 21:00:00|2017-08-21 22:00:00|        11|
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I want to build a HTML-table, showing a timetable for the current day, also representing all free timeslots.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Facility #11</th>
    <th>Facility #12</th>
 </thead>

  <tr>
    <td>08:00</td>
    <td>09:00</td>
    ...
    <td>21:00</td>
    <td>22:00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    ...
    <td>User 100</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

Time    Facility #11    Facility #12
08:00   09:00   21:00   22:00
        User 100
```

To populate the table automatically, I thought it would be a good idea to
create an associative array containing all possible starttimes as the key and the booking information as the value, if existing.

```
array(xy) {["08:00"][1]=>string(0) "" [2]=>string(0) "" ["09:00"][1]=>string(0) "" [2]=>string(0) "" ... ["21:00"] [1]=>string(3) "100" [2]=>string(2) "11" ... }
```

Therefore I created two arrays which I want to combine to one.

Array 1 - Starttimes

```
array1 = array();
   for ($hours = 8; $hours <= 22; $hours++) {
      for ($m = 0; $m < 60; $m += 60) {
          $starttime_html = sprintf('%02u:%02u', $hours, $m);
          $array1[$starttime_html]='';

      }
    }
```

Array 2 - Bookings

```
array2 = array();
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, user_id, starttime, facility_id FROM mpbs_bookings WHERE starttime >= '2017-08-21 00:00:00'");
$statement->execute(array($id));
while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
   $starttime_currentday = explode(" ",$row['starttime']);
   $starttime_curr_hm = substr($starttime_currentday[1],0,5);
   array_push($array2, array($starttime_curr_hm, $row['facility_id'], $row['user_id']));
 }
```

Now I do not find a way to combine those two arrays. 
Besides that, I would be glad about any suggestions on how to achieve my goal.

---

Here are the contents of boths arrays:

```
print_r(array1);

Array ( [08:00] => [09:00] => ... => [21:00] => [22:00]=> )


print_r(array2);

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 18:00 [1] => 6 [2] => 22 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 19:00 [1] => 4 [2] => 11 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 20:00 [1] => 2 [2] => 5 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 20:00 [1] => 9 [2] => 8 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 21:00 [1] => 11 [2] => 34 ) )
```

Thanks in advance.

Lars

Comment: What do you need the second array for? Just use nested loops to output your days and hours, and inside check if you have an entry in your data array for the current date and time ... if so, output the data, else “nothing” as the content for the current table cell ...

Comment: I agree with CBroe, you don't really need the first array. However, if you are adamant on using it, you can use the `array_merge` function to achieve what you wanted. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comments. I am trying around with both suggestions, but I do not get to my goal yet... I am not very experienced in PHP programming.

Comment: Can you please `print_r($array1)` and `print_r($array2)` please and post in your OP? Only need 2 or 3 pieces of the data not the full set.

Comment: I added `print_r($array1)` and `print_r($array2)` to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I made a change to the structure of Array2. I did this so we can make use of array_merge. array_merge works by matching the array keys and replacing the old (array 1) with our new (array 2).

Please see the ammended code to array2 and a solution to print out the output

```
$array2 = array();
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, user_id, starttime, facility_id FROM  mpbs_bookings WHERE starttime >= '2017-08-21 00:00:00'");
$statement->execute(array($id));

while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
   $starttime_currentday = explode(" ",$row['starttime']);
   $starttime_curr_hm = substr($starttime_currentday[1],0,5);

   $array2[$starttime_curr_hm] =  
       array('facliId'=>$row['facility_id'],'userid'=> $row['user_id']);
 }

$mergedArray = array_merge($array1,$array2);
foreach($mergedArray as $date=>$value){
   echo $date;
   echo 'Holding facility_id of '.$value['facliId'].' and user_id of '.$value['userid'].'</br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. Unfortunately it did not work as expected.
I changed the way the arrays are generated and I think now it is working.
Therefore I used a function I found in another thread:

    `function array_push_assoc (&$array, $key, $value) {'
       '$array[$key] = $value;'
       'return $array;`

     ...

     `array_push_assoc($array1, $starttime_html, array('facID'=>'','userID'=>''));`

    ...
    
    `array_push_assoc($array2, $starttime_curr_hm, array('facID'=>$row['facility_id'],'userID'=> $row['user_id']) );`

Comment: Can you please post the `print_r($mergedArray)` contents

Comment: @Gardinero I found the problem that you had with my code and I have corrected it. if you have found another solution then fair enough :)

Comment: Here you find the contens with your code:
    `Array ( [08:00] => [09:00] => [10:00] => [11:00] => [12:00] => [13:00] => [14:00] => [15:00] => [16:00] => [17:00] => [18:00] => [19:00] => [20:00] => [21:00] => [22:00] => [0] => Array ( [18:00] => Array ( [facliId] => 6 [userid] => 0 ) ) [1] => Array ( [18:00] => Array ( [facliId] => 4 [userid] => 0 ) ) [2] => Array ( [19:00] => Array ( [facliId] => 2 [userid] => 0 ) ) [3] => Array ( [20:00] => Array ( [facliId] => 9 [userid] => 0 ) ) [4] => Array ( [21:00] => Array ( [facliId] => 11 [userid] => 0 ) ) ) `

Comment: Thanks a lot! The corrected code is working! I will check, which solutions works out best for me.
Again, thank you for your effort.

Comment: No problem, happy to be of assistance